# How to acess contacts of iPhone in IOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

I want to show contacts and details of contacts in my application.List of contacts and after selecting any contact details of that contact will show on next page using addressbook. I am working on IOS 6.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following code for retrieving contact details.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    contactList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ABAddressBookRef m_addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    if (!m_addressbook) {
        NSLog(@"opening address book");
    }

    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(m_addressbook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(m_addressbook);

    for (int i=0;i &lt; nPeople;i++) { 
        NSMutableDictionary *dOfPerson=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople,i);

        //For username and surname
        ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        CFStringRef firstName, lastName;
        firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        lastName  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        [dOfPerson setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName] forKey:@"name"];

        //For Email ids
        ABMutableMultiValueRef eMail  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(eMail) &gt; 0) {
            [dOfPerson setObject:(NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(eMail, 0) forKey:@"email"];

        }

        //For Phone number
        NSString* mobileLabel;
        for(CFIndex i = 0; i &lt; ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++) {
            mobileLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
            if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
            {
                [dOfPerson setObject:(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i) forKey:@"Phone"];
            }
            else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel])
            {
                [dOfPerson setObject:(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i) forKey:@"Phone"];
                break ;
            }

        [contactList addObject:dOfPerson];
        CFRelease(ref);
        CFRelease(firstName);
        CFRelease(lastName);
    }
    NSLog(@"array is %@",contactList);
    }
}
```

You can download sample code and find more details from [the tutorial on my site](http://sugartin.info/2011/09/07/get-information-from-iphone-address-book-in-contacts/).

Answer (score 2):

**Add Framwork**

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBook/ABPerson.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
```

**use delegate**

```
<ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate,ABPersonViewControllerDelegate,ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate,ABUnknownPersonViewControllerDelegate>
```

You can show your contact by `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
        [[picker navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
        picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
        // Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
        NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],nil];

        picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
        // Show the picker
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
```

**and after you initialize then you need to use following method**

```
#pragma mark - ABPeopelPickerNavigationController Delegate and DataSource Methods

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
   // For get People detail
}

- (void)unknownPersonViewController:(ABUnknownPersonViewController *)unknownCardViewController didResolveToPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
}

- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
}

- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier;
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ABRecordID recordId;
ABAddressBookRef _addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreate ();
NSArray* allPeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(_addressBookRef);
NSString* compositeName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName((ABRecordRef)record);
recordId = ABRecordGetRecordID(record);
ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonEmailProperty);
```

Do proper release just a snippet