# Contact Sync in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to create iOS contact management and organization app. In that I need a feature where a person in a group can share all contacts of a group to the group members. If group members accept the request, the contacts on that person's get overridden.

As of now, users are storing all their contacts on iCloud. Now I'm looking towards a mechanism to share the contacts to group users. I'm okay to use another option in addition to iCloud for temporary storage. Eg. Parse.

I would like to understand the best possible way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I see three parts to this flow:

1. Gathering Contacts
2. Sending Contacts to server
3. Downloading and integrating contacts

There are [plenty](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-import-contact-address-book/) of [tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/63885/address-book-tutorial-in-ios) on [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356406/how-to-acess-contacts-of-iphone-in-ios-6) [to](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6bymuddrwxbmkp/AddressBook.zip?dl=0) get contacts in iOS. Do you have the logic on how to organize the contacts into the groups you want?

Parse could be a good solution for your backend. iCloud is great for sharing data between devices for a single user but is rather weak when it comes to sharing between multiple users. You'll need a user registration and identification process as well, and security will be important when dealing with users' personal information. I'd recommend using another authentication service, such as [Facebook login](https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios), [Google OAuth](https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction), or [IBM Bluemix](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/We0d917403ade_46b2_8991_d1eabb8126f6/page/Using%20IBM%20SSO%20Service%20in%20a%20BlueMix%20Application). In terms of storing data and transmitting it, I'd recommend taking a look at the [Parse tutorial for Anypic](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic) and work on reconfiguring the general idea to your own needs.

Lastly, you'll need to reverse the first step by downloading the contacts, reading through the users contacts, and then adding in only the new contacts and new data about contacts already on the device.